# Run Linux terminal commands in Android program

Tags: android, exec, invoke-command

I am developing a small app that would synchronize a directory present in my android phone with that of my laptop. I rooted my phone and also installed rsync in that so as to synchronize the directories across my phone and laptop. I checked it manually and everything seems working ( I am able to synchronize phone's directory with my laptop ). Now i would like to do this programmatically. How can i do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ls");
```

for running native commands in Android app.

Check http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App